# Relative compactness in locally compact metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

> Let $(X,d)$ be a locally compact metric space and $Y\subset X$ a
> compact set. Then there exists $r>0$ such that $V_r(Y)$ is relatively
> compact in $X$.

Since $X$ is locally compact, for each $x\in Y$, there  exists a compact neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$. Clearly $(\mathring{U}_x)_{x\in E}$ forms an open covering of $Y$. As $Y$ is compact, there exist a finite subset $\{y_1,\ldots, y_k\}$ of $Y$ such that
$$Y\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^k\mathring{U}_{y_i}\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^kU_{y_i}.$$
Note that $\bigcup_{i=1}^kU_{y_i}$ is compact as it is a finite union of compact sets. Furthermore, it is a neighborhood of $Y$. This implies that there exists $r>0$ such that $V_r(Y)\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^kU_{y_i}$.

How can I use the above to deduce that $\overline{V_r(Y)}$ is compact in $X$?

**Notation:** $V_r(Y)=\{x\in X\ |\ d(x,Y)<r\}$ for $0<r$.

Comment: $\operatorname{cl}V_r(Y)$ is a closed subset of the compact set $\bigcup_{i=1}^kU_{y_i}$, so it’s compact.

Comment: Yes I see, Thank you

Comment: You’re welcome.